# SQL multiple date from single column to multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

How can I move a column of dates like below.

```
User              Date
====              ====
001               2012/12/01 09:00
001               2012/12/01 11:00
001               2012/12/01 12:00
001               2012/12/01 13:00
001..             ...
```

and list them like below.

```
User  date         time1   time2   time3  time4    time5  
001   2012/12/01   09:00   11:00   12:00  13:00    14:00
```

Thanks Bluefeet for the solution.  I tested the script and got the following result.

```
2   2012/11/04  09:00:00.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   2012/11/08  NULL    09:00:00.000    18:00:00.000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   2012/11/09  NULL    NULL    NULL    09:00:00.000    18:00:00.000    NULL    NULL
2   2012/11/10  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    09:00:00.000    18:00:00.000
```

The time seems to skip to the last null column for the same user at the next date?  is there a way for me to arrange them in order starting from the first column for the next date for the same user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you previously tagged questions with a sql server tag so I will assume that is the database.

You can perform this operation using the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function in SQL Server.  There are two ways that you can do this either static where you hard-code all of the values or dynamic where the values are determined at run-time.

**Static Pivot:**

```
select *
from 
(
  select [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) date,
    right(convert(varchar(50), date, 121), 12) time
    , 'time'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) order by date) as varchar(10)) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(time)
  for rn in (time1, time2, time3, time4)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4974b/8)

**Dynamic Pivot:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('time'+cast(row_number() over(partition by [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) order by date) as varchar(10))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [user], date,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) date,
                  right(convert(varchar(50), date, 121), 12) time
                  , ''time''+cast(row_number() over(partition by [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) order by date) as varchar(10)) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(time)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4c0b/2)

**Aggregate/CASE version:**

If for some reason you do not want to use the `PIVOT` function, then you can also use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

```
select [user], date,
  max(case when rn = 1 then time end) Time1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then time end) Time2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then time end) Time3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then time end) Time4
from
(
  select [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) date,
    right(convert(varchar(50), date, 121), 12) time
    , row_number() over(partition by [user], convert(varchar(10), date, 111) order by date)) rn
  from yourtable
) src
group by [user], date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4c0b/5)

All three produce the same result:

```
| USER |       DATE |        TIME1 |        TIME2 |        TIME3 |        TIME4 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  001 | 2012/12/01 | 09:00:00.000 | 11:00:00.000 | 12:00:00.000 | 13:00:00.000 |
|  001 | 2012/12/02 | 09:00:00.000 | 11:00:00.000 | 12:00:00.000 | 13:00:00.000 |
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I am using SQL 2008

Comment: @user1833676 see my edit, I had to change the `row_number()` to `partition by` both the user and the date values